# noise reduction on multiple wav file in python

Tags: python, loops, wav, noise-reduction

I have used the code from
https://github.com/davidpraise45/Audio-Signal-Processing

to make a function to run it on an entire folder which contains around 100 wav files, but unable to get output cant understand what seems to be the problem.

```
def noise_reduction(dirName):
    types = ('*.wav', '*.aif',  '*.aiff', '*.mp3', '*.au', '*.ogg')
    wav_file_list = []
    for files in types:
        wav_file_list.extend(glob.glob(os.path.join(dirName, files)))

    wav_file_list = sorted(wav_file_list)    
    wav_file_list2 = []
    for i, wavFile in enumerate(wav_file_list):
        #samples = get_samples(wavFile,)
        (Frequency, samples)=read(wavFile)
        FourierTransformation = sp.fft(samples) # Calculating the fourier transformation of the signal
        scale = sp.linspace(0, Frequency, len(samples))
        b,a = signal.butter(5, 9800/(Frequency/2), btype='highpass') # ButterWorth filter 4350
        filteredSignal = signal.lfilter(b,a,samples)
        c,d = signal.butter(5, 200/(Frequency/4), btype='lowpass') # ButterWorth low-filter
        newFilteredSignal = signal.lfilter(c,d,filteredSignal) # Applying the filter to the signal
        write(New,wavFile, Frequency, newFilteredSignal)


noise_reduction("C:\\Users\\adity\\Desktop\\capstone\\hindi_dia_2\\sad\\sad_1.wav")
```

Comment: What is the variable `New`? Did you mean to add the string `"New"` to the beginning of the filename of each file you `write()`?

Comment: yes, I want the modified file to be named starting with new

Answer (score 0):

[`scipy.io.wavfile.read`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.read.html) only supports the WAV format. It can not read `aif`, `aiff`, `mp3`, `au`, or `ogg` files.

You have four arguments to the [`scipy.io.wavfile.write`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.write.html) function that only takes three. `New,wavFile` should most likely be `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(wavFile)`, `"New"+os.path.basename(wavFile))`. This create a file with the `New` prefix in the same directory as the original. If you want to create them in the current directory instead use `"New"+os.path.basename(wavFile)`.

You are passing a filename, not the name of a directory to your function:

```
noise_reduction("C:\\Users\\adity\\Desktop\\capstone\\hindi_dia_2\\sad\\sad_1.wav")
```

should likely be:

```
noise_reduction("C:\\Users\\adity\\Desktop\\capstone\\hindi_dia_2\\sad")
```

This causes the `glob` pattern to end up being: `C:\\Users\\adity\\Desktop\\capstone\\hindi_dia_2\\sad\\sad_1.wav\\*.wav`. This pattern has no matches unless `sad_1.wav` was a directory and it had files in it that ended with `.wav`.

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply, but wen i run the whole directory it gets hanged,the reason which im not understanding.I will try your solution and get back to you about the scipy.io

Comment: hey i tired your solution my kernel is still running n no output